# Cant get a 200 response on a specific condition

Tags: node.js, sails.js, response

I am working on an NodeJs / Sails backend on an app.
The function I am struggling with is suppose to select all games (foot) that ended between 3 & 4 days ago an generate a notifications (actu) to all the players of the game to notify them of the trophies (best & worst player of the game).

I just added a condition in order to prevent the generation of a notification (actu) if the game (foot) doesnt have any trophies. This is the all function :

```
Foot.query("SELECT id FROM foot WHERE foot.date <'"+nowMinus3d+"' AND date >'"+nowMinus4d+"'", function(err, results){
  _.each(results.rows, function(result, err){
    Player.query("SELECT player.user, player.foot FROM player WHERE (player.statut = 2 OR player.statut = 3) AND player.foot ='"+result["id"]+"'", function(err, players){
      async.each(players.rows, function(player, callback){
        Trophe.findOne({foot: player["foot"]}).exec(function findOneCB(err, trophe){
           if (err) {console.log(err);}
           if (trophe){
              console.log(trophe);
              Actu.create({user:player["user"], related_user:player["user"], typ:'resultFoot', related_stuff: player["foot"]}).exec(function(err,actu){
                if(err){
                  console.log(err);
                }
                else {
                  Connexion.findOne({user:player["user"]}).exec(function(err, connexion){
                    if (connexion){
                      sails.sockets.emit(connexion.socket_id,'notif',actu);
                      callback();
                    }
                    else {
                      callback();
                    }
                  });
                }
              });
            }
          else {
            console.log("Personne n'a été élu sur ce foot")
          }
        });
      },function(){
        res.status(200).end();
      })
    })
  })
})
```

So 1) I select the foot that ended between 3 and 4 days ago
2) I select the players that are linked to thes football games
3) For each of them I generate an Actu if the football game has a trophey
4) at the end of my loop (`async.each`), `res.status(200).end();`

If I have a trophey, everything is fine and I get my 200 resp. But when there is no trophey, I get my `console.log("personne n'a été élu sur ce foot")` printed, but I never get my 200 response.

Shouldnt I be getting a 200 response even though there are now trophies as `res.status(200).end();` is the callback of the async.each function ? It is not dependant on the existence of a trophy. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you have not used the callback, so async can't complete. Just change to:

```
console.log("Personne n'a été élu sur ce foot");
callback();
```